# sorting multidimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort a 2d array in java. The first column is an int that describes a kind of permission and the second is another integer that describes a category of application.
I want to sort the first column leaving the second as it is. 
So for example if i put as parameters [0][0] I will return the most used permission in that category.

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for your help

Comment: Can you add some code that you may have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting Java Multidimensional Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076982/sorting-java-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Arrays#sort(T[],Comparator<? super T>)` function

```
      int array [][] = {{1,11},{2,34},{3,8},{8,4},{7,23}};

        java.util.Arrays.sort(array, new java.util.Comparator<int[]>() {
            public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
                return b[0] - a[0];
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
    class 2DcolumnComparator implements Comparator {
        private int columnToSortOn;

        2DcolumnComparator(int columnToSortOn) {
        this.columnToSortOn = columnToSortOn;
    }

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
     String[] row1 = (String[])o1;
     String[] row2 = (String[])o2;

     return row1[columnToSortOn].compareTo(row2[columnToSortOn]);
    }
   }
```

Comment: It might be useful to show how someone would use the Comparator. ie. Arrays.sort()

Comment: While `Comparator` may be the way to go (I have a feeling the OP has left out some important information), it's usually better to use the genericized version.